# Print nth line below given

Tags: java

I have this code to find a given line and print the 5 lines below it. I'd like to modify it so instead, it prints **only** the nth line below.

Example:

- cat
- dog
- pig
- horse

If I wanted to find the line contained cat and I wanted to print 2nd line below it, it would print 'pig'. Or if I wanted to print the 1st line below it, it would print 'dog'.

Alternatively, if the given line contained 'dog' and I wanted to print the first line below that, it would print 'pig'.

Here's the code:

```
if (line.contains("string")) {
    for (int a = 0; in.hasNextLine() && a < 6; a++) {
         System.out.println(line);
         line = in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

How would I modify it to do what I want? Thanks.

Comment: ok, what is your question ?

Comment: How would I modify the code?

Comment: If the condition `a < 6` works for the 5th line after the line you want, then the nth line would need the condition `a < n + 1` (or `a <= n`).

Answer (score 0):

Store the line number ( `lineNum` ), then loop until that line number is reached. Then print the last stored line in `line` from the last iteration of `nextLine()`.

```
public void printLineN(int lineNum) {

    if ( line.contains("string") ) {
        for (int a = 0; in.hasNextLine() && a <= lineNum; a++)
            line = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Or, use `LineNumberReader`'s `getLineNumber()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
String word = ..
int n = ...

if (line.contains(word)) {
    int a = 0;
    while (in.hashNextLine && a++ != n)
        line = in.nextLine();

    if (a == n) {
        System.out.println(line);
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("Error: There is only " + a + " entries after the word " + word);
    }    
}
```

Once the word is found, the while loop will try to advance the reader to the nth line after the found word. If there is enough lines available, the nth line would be printed, otherwise error will be printed.